# How to get a count of rows based on the elements of a column of lists?

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataset with 2 columns. One is a client ID and the other is a list of products purchased. Data is sorted by ID. Each row represents a transaction. I have to pull out the top 20 products present in the most number of transactions.

So the data may look like:

ID  | Product_List

1   |   92

2   |   88

2   |   88, 89

2   |   88, 91, 90

3   |   130, 88, 90, 92

3   |   130, 88, 90, 92

3   |   130, 88, 91

3   |   130, 88

3   |   130, 88

I need to get the top 5 products which are bought with the most frequency. Product IDs do not get repeated within a list.

I want to avoid using for loops, and that's really where I'm stuck right now.

So my output would be:

Product | No. of Txns

88      |  8

130     |  5

90      |  3

92      |  3

91      |  2

Apologies, I don't know how to format a table on this. I've done this using a for loop, by unlisting each list into a bunch of columns, and then just run a count over the entire thing, but this seems like a very inefficient way to code. I'm not really clear on how to work with data where a column is comprised of lists, I would ideally like to vectorise an operation like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help:

```
library(tidyverse)

# example data
dt = data.frame(ID = 1:3,
                Product_List = c("92","88, 89", "88, 92"), stringsAsFactors = F)

dt %>%
  separate_rows(Product_List) %>%     # split strings to different rows
  count(Product_List) %>%             # count elements
  top_n(2, n) %>%                     # select top 2 based on counts
  rename(No_of_Txns = n)              # rename counts column

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   Product_List No_of_Txns
#   <chr>             <int>
# 1 88                    2
# 2 92                    2
```

You can change this to `top_n(5, n)` to get the top 5 in your real example.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to AntoniosK's solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(Product_List) %>%
  group_by(Product_List) %>%
  summarise(No_of_Txns = n()) %>%
  arrange(desc(No_of_Txns))
```